# ASP.NET MVC ViewModel Path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

When creating a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project, there is no pre-created directory for storing ViewModel objects (presumably because this is an optional pattern).  I know the location is arbitrary, but is there a generally accepted path where these should be placed?

Comment: There is no such standard; However having it in a separate directory like 'ViewModels' would give a logical way of arranging the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the ViewModels should be in the same project  of the Views but it is arbitrary

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Model folder. This folder should contain view models. Domain models or entity models should be part of another assembly, i.e. a data access layer assembly. Same for DTOs.